# How to unit test Finder Sync Extension?

Tags: xcode, unit-testing, tdd, findersync

Is there any way Finder Sync Extension can be unit tested?

Is only way to test the extension to factor the code into a framework and then have the framework tested?

Comment: Your suggestion of factoring the code into a framework and then testing the framework is the only way I have been able to accomplish this. It's too bad we can't test the extension code directly.